# Send Docker Entrypoint logs to APP in realtime

Tags: docker, logging, netlify, vercel, surge.sh

I'm looking for ideas to send Docker Logs for each runs to be sent to my application in realtime. I'm looking ways this can be done. Please let me know how this can be done.

Let me know if you have done this already or know how this can be achieved. I want to build feature similar to Netlify or vercel where they show you all build log on UI in realtime. I want something similar for my node application.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this with Vercel and Log Drains.

> Log Drains make it easy to collect logs from your deployments and forward them to archival, search, and alerting services by sending them via HTTPS, HTTP, TLS, and TCP once a new log line is created.
>
> At the time of writing, we currently support 3 types of Log Drains:
>
> - JSON
> - NDJSON
> - Syslog
>
> Along with Log Drains, we are introducing two new open-source integrations with logging services for you to start using them today: LogDNA and Datadog.

Install the integration: https://vercel.com/integrations?category=logging

See the announcement blog post: https://vercel.com/blog/log-drains

Note that Vercel does not allow Docker deployments, but does support [Serverless Functions](https://vercel.com/docs/v2/serverless-functions/introduction).

Comment: I guess i might have confused you some way. I want to implement feature in my saas APP where logs can be shown from my docker container to user on browser. Like vercel or netlify shows live logs from build process to user browser. I want to know how that can be done. Thank you for detailed reply.